# How to export and version control all metadata of an org

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, org, versioning

How to export and version control all metadata of an org, by saying that, I mean if I import all these metadata into a brand new org, it will create an identical org as the original org. THIS HAS TO BE TRUE! if not, what else except metadata do I need to duplicate an org?(empty org contains no data)

I think my question is confusing, so I split into many questions:

- does metadata contains EVERYTHING BUT NOT DATA about an org? if not, what's not included?please provide reference.
- is there a tool/method to export EVERYTHING of an org? what is it?
- If Eclipse IDE can only export most of the org,then what is missing?
- If workbench can only export most of the org,then what is missing?
- how to version control the whole org?

Comment: You could spin up sandboxes from PROD every so often if you just need backups

Answer (score 1):

You'll discover that there are a number of metadata types that aren't supported by the Metadata API. You can find a list of them in the documentation under [Unsupported Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm). I recommend you go through the [Trailhead Application Lifecycle Management module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/alm_deployment) which discusses these issues and different strategies for dealing with them.

Answer (score 1):

*how to version control the whole org?*

Check these out - note they all various fees; but they are, essentially, GUI's for the Metadata API. I have only used Flosum, which I have liked thus far, and have only briefly demo'd Snapshot and AutoRabit. They all have version control.
For Flosum and Snapshot, you get trial versions to play with. And all of them support all the Metadata that Salesforce provides access to.

**Flosum**
http://www.flosum.com/

- Separate package; native SF UI
- Company is about 1 to 2 years old
- Modest price, though we are nonprofit, so i can't say how that translates to biz

**Snapshot**
http://www.dreamfactory.com/force.com/snapshot

- Separate, native to Salesforce; custom UI within tab
- Robust
- A bit higher cost - have been around for many years
- Min licenses/cost - not sure how much i think. $5k min maybe?

**AutoRabit** ( i would give the URL, but i can't because of reputation - see autorabit.com)

- Separate custom UI from their site
- New (1 to 2 years)
- Robust - and even some clever workarounds.
- Have a very nice onboarding process
- Minimum of 3 users/annual license